# How do I get a value from query and add the value by 1 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I really appreciate any respond for this simple question.

```
test = Model.find_by_sql("SELECT number FROM tbl_one LIMIT 1").each do |a|
  p = a('number')
  puts p
end
```

Look, I mean, after store a value to `p`, how do I add the `p` value by 1.
Hide   Copy Code

`puts p + 1`

I tried it but doesn't work. Based on what I saw, the 'p' doesn't really store the value, but I don't really sure. Anyway, I'm new on Ruby and Rails

Any solution?
Thanks.

Note: I asked this question in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060582/How-do-I-get-a-value-from-query-and-add-the-value) also. Just to make sure quick responds. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ups!
Sorry, my mistake.. I found it!

`p = a('number').to_i`

Then I can add the value by 1 easily.. 
Thanks!